# Object_Id in Sys.Tables view

Tags: sql-server-2008

when you query select * from sys_tables.  one of the fields returned is object_id.  Is this permenant id?  Meaning can I use that Id to FK relationship?

What I am trying to accomplish is... All my tables have a inactiveDate and inactiveREasonId fields.  I have table that has InactiveReasons that are based on tables.  So instead of storing the TableName in the InactiveREason table I want to store the ObjectId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I would not rely on this (and there is no way to specify a foreign key -> object_id anyway). The reason? If you ever drop / re-create the table, or script out the database to deploy elsewhere, you'll get completely different object_ids. You should treat the object_id like the sequence number of the receipt you get from the donut shop - really not relevant to you, but relevant for the internal workings of the cash register and for the shop's accounting.